# AEM : How to Iterate a HTL list in reverse order?

Tags: aem, htl

Using data-sly-list the elements are printed in the order as they are.

Is there a way in HTL using which we can print the list items in reverse order?

e.g.

if the list contains 1,2,3,4 I want to print 4,3,2,1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data-sly-list` is not currently having control to handle iteration order of list. You would have to change the order in the data you are feeding to list using [JavaScript or Java Use API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/use-api.html), following is example of JavaScript use API

**In logic.js file**

```
use(function () {
  var someArrayVar = [1,2,3,4];
  return{
   someArrayRev : someArrayVar.reverse() 
  };
});
```

**In HTML Markup**

```
 <div data-sly-use.logic="logic.js">
   <div data-sly-list="${logic.someArrayRev}">
       ${item}
   </div>
 <div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.